# how do you find the values in array A that their mods is array B

Tags: c#, linq

I need fastest way to find the values in array A that their mods is array B when divided by 4:

```
A = {4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

B={2,3}

result={6,7,10}
```

mine:

```
  foreach (int b in B)
       {
        S=  A.Where(n => n % 4 == b).ToArray();

        foreach (int s in S)
        {
            newlist.Add(s); 

        }
       }
   newlist.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: What do you mean 'fastest way'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not:

```
var query = A.Where(a => B.Contains(a % 4))
             .ToArray();
```

If `B` could be large, you could create a `HashSet<int>` instead, but if it's *really* going to be mod 4, there's no point.

Alternatively, assuming you know that every element in `A` and `B` is positive (and that `B` doesn't have any silly values, like 5), you can map `B` to a `bool[4]` and use `& 3` instead of `% 4`:

```
var truth = new bool[4];
foreach (var b in B)
{
    truth[b] = true;
}
var query = A.Where(a => truth[a & 3]).ToArray();
```

Comment: You have to know for sure that all values in `B` are positive, too. Arrays don't like it if you try to access their `-1`st element, regardless of reading or writing.

Answer (score 1):

A little code-review:

```
foreach (int b in B)
   {
    S=  A.Where(n => n % 4 == b).ToArray();

    foreach (int s in S)
    {
        newlist.Add(s); 

    }
   }
newlist.Distinct().ToArray();
```

You don't need the ToArray() in Where(...).ToArray().
And the foreach loop can be replace with AddRange()

```
   foreach (int b in B)
   {
      var S = A.Where(n => n % 4 == b);
      newlist.AddRange(S); 
   }
   var result = newlist.Distinct().ToList();
```

Try to use less arrays. `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` are far more useful.